# How to use Orchard Disqus Feature

Tags: comments, orchardcms, disqus

I'm new to orchard core and I'm trying to create a blog. About a month ago creating comment in orchard was available by just enabling disqus feature but now it is not possible for me. I enabled the feature and added the part to the content and it just create a check box which says: Hide Comments and nothing more happen.
can any one help me?
thanks

ps: I'm using asp net core 5 and orchardcore.application.cms.targets\1.0.0-rc2-16145\ and disqus.orchardcore\1.0.0-rc2-10019\

Comment: Anything like an error message in the F12 JavaScript console?

Comment: no.there is no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the Readme, you need to edit the settings of the Disqus Part and enter the name of the site that you created on https://disqus.com/.

Comment: thanks for your answer and I appreciate it. I watched your video on YouTube and started to do the same. But the new problem is that I still don't have a site and I'm working on my local, so when I'm creating a site on disqus it asks a website URL which I don't have. What should I do?

Comment: You can modify the disque script so it uses localhost.